# Relation/connection between $n!$ or $e$ and $2^n$

Tags: soft-question, exponential-function, factorial

What is the relation/connection between $n!$ or $e$  and $2^n$ ? Is the there a relation/connection between $n!$ or $e$ and $2^n$?

Comment: Define 'relation.' There's [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) that gives an asymptotic formula for $n!$ involving $e^n$.

Answer (score 12):

The first thing in my head after reading the question:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^n}{n!} = e^2$$

Comment: Very nice! I've thought a bit towards this and that - but your proposal is so simple :+)

Comment: what is the intuition behind that $e$ takes the other's bottom on its shoulder, in summations?

Comment: There was no intuitive reasoning, simply a definition. As a power series, we have (and can *define*) $e^x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$, which converges for all complex numbers. You happened to ask about functions/numbers that would appear in the case $x=2$(!)

Comment: thats tautological, perhaps my problem is with *+-% etc. Anyway:)

Comment: in response to @waqarahmad comment ''what is the intuition behind that e takes the other's bottom on its shoulder, in summations?'' [Formal Power Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_formal_Laurent_series)